# Python plotly.express - add labels in scatter_geo

Tags: python, label, plotly, scatter

I need to add static labels on markers in scatter_geo vizualization. I added `text='data'`, but nothing had happend:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

rows=[['501-600','15','122.58333','45.36667'],
      ['till 500','4','12.5','27.5'],
      ['more 1001','41','-115.53333','38.08'],
      ]

colmns=['bins','data','longitude','latitude']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=colmns)
df = df.astype({"data": int})

fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      color='bins',
                      text='data',
                      opacity=0.5,size='data',
                      projection="natural earth")

fig.show()
fig.write_html('first_figure.html', auto_open=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are an `update_trace` away from a solution. With `go.Scattergeo` you can use the parameters `mode` and `textposition` inside the method while with `plotly.express` you should change after.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

rows=[['501-600','15','122.58333','45.36667'],
      ['till 500','4','12.5','27.5'],
      ['more 1001','41','-115.53333','38.08'],
      ]

colmns=['bins','data','longitude','latitude']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=colmns)
df = df.astype({"data": int})

fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      color='bins',
                      text='data',
                      opacity=0.5,
                      size='data',
                      projection="natural earth")
# This
fig.update_traces(textposition="top center",
                  mode='markers+text')

fig.show()
```

** UPDATE**

A possible solution in order to avoid the problems in legend is

```py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

rows=[['501-600','15','122.58333','45.36667'],
      ['till 500','4','12.5','27.5'],
      ['more 1001','41','-115.53333','38.08'],
      ]

colmns=['bins','data','longitude','latitude']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=colmns)
df = df.astype({"data": int})

fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      color='bins',
                      opacity=0.5,
                      size='data',
                      projection="natural earth")

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=df["longitude"],
              lat=df["latitude"],
              text=df["data"],
              textposition="middle center",
              mode='text',
              showlegend=False))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, it really works now, but also there appears letters "Aa" above markers in legend. How to get rid of them now?

Comment: Apparently this is a problem with plotly see [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2967) and possible [solution](https://community.plotly.com/t/editing-the-legend-symbols/2113/5)

Comment: @Dimitry I guess that this is a different problem and should be addressed with another question and or an issue on github.

Comment: An other option could be play with traces and legends.

Answer (score 1):

Late but as of now (Jan 2023) the following **is working** (assuming 'data' is a df column):

```
px.scatter_geo(text='data' .....
```